# SSH to host#1 and then ssh to host#2 from host#1 and then run command and then stay connected

Tags: ssh

Im trying to SSH to host #1, who has access to host #2, 
and on host #2 I want to run a command. All from my local machine.

This bit works fine:

```
    ssh host1 -t "command; ssh user@host2"
```

But, on host2, I also want to cd to a directory and then stay connected

I tried using this:

```
    ssh host1 -t "command; ssh user@host2 -t 'command; cd /some/path/'"
```

The output I get is:

```
    Connection to host2 closed.
    Connection to host1 closed.
```

And ends up on my local machine

The expected result was my session being on host2 in the /some/path/ directory thru host1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `tmux` or `screen` as suggested by @heemayl, one can also use `bash`:

```
ssh host1 -t "command; ssh user@host2 -t 'command; cd /some/path/; bash'"
```

Comment: Thats a good one as far as the OP's requirement is concerned. +1.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and doesnt require additional packages on host2 as @heemayl suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Install `screen` or `tmux` in "host2" then running the following will keep the session alive:

```
ssh host1 -t "command; ssh user@host2 -t 'command; cd /some/path/; screen'"
```

In case of you command i.e. `ssh host1 -t "command; ssh user@host2 -t 'command; cd /some/path/'"`, the session will be closed after running the commands. But if you use `screen` or `tmux` the remote session will be kept alive.

Check the manpages of [screen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man1/screen.1.html) and [tmux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html) for details. `tmux` is the newer approach to solve the same problem `screen` solves.