# SSH via jump server and then use a command

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have a jump server that I need as a bridge when running commands on another server.

I set up the jump server in my ssh config to be `hopping` and on the jump server, I set the final destination as `lb3`.

`ssh -t hopping ssh lb3`

The above command works. I end up at my final destination and my terminal is interactive.

However, when I want to run more complex commands I seem to have trouble with correct escaping...

For example, I'm trying to run this:

```
ssh -t hopping ssh lb3 "varnishadm -S /opt/varnish_secret -T 127.0.0.1:6082 ban 'req.url ~ .'"
```

Error message:

```
Command failed with error code 106 expected conditional (~, !~, == or !=) got "/home/username"
```

I have tried a few different ways of escaping but I can't say that I really know what I'm doing in this case. Does anyone who is more experienced know what I need to escape to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Just before I posted my question, a stackoverflow recommendation for this pointed me to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/584590/579139)

I changed my command according to that answer and this is now what I have and it works :)

```
ssh -t hopping "command; ssh -t lb3 'command; varnishadm -S /opt/varnish_secret -T 127.0.0.1:6082 ban \"req.url ~ .\"'"
```